# How to know record in Queued scheduled action

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-job

We had a process builder with scheduled actions. But the logic in it was wrong and records were scheduled with that logic. Today i have updated the logic of process, But some scheduled actions with older Version of process are still in queue.

So i was wondering if we can somehow find the record associated in particular scheduled Action. Unders Flows...-> pending actions, I can see the scheduled action. And when i open it, there is no details pointing to record for which this action has been scheduled.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Am not sure, but you can querry `FlowRecordRelation` to get related records to the flow. cant confirm as I have never tried it

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can not find the respective records for those Flow Interviews directly.
You can find the Flow name of the Interview. By knowing the Flow name, you can find the condition of the flow and then you can create a report or query with same condition on object to find records.

Otherwise you can reach out to Salesforce Support.